# Significance of negative setup and hold time

Tags: flipflop, setup

What do you mean by negative setup and hold time i.e what happens if hold time is negative or setup time is negative. Does -ve setup or hold have any advantage ?

Answer (score 7):

Setup times and hold times describe the limits *relative to the active clock edge* of a "window" within which the input data **must** be valid for the data to be reliably recognized. The diagram below (you can ignore the bottom Q output part) shows the situation for assumed positive hold and setup times, but you can imagine them negative.

[image]

If setup time is negative, then the absolute latest that the data can become valid is actually after the active clock edge, Obviously the hold time *must* be positive *and of greater magnitude* or there would be no window for data validity.

If the hold time is negative, then the absolute earliest the data no longer needs to be valid is before the active clock edge, so it can change just before the clock edge and the previous value will be correctly recognized. Obviously, the setup time must be positive and of *greater* magnitude or there would be no window.

As to possible advantages- think about the situation where you are trying to increase clock frequency as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer. I have a quick question. Let's suppose we have a positive setup time and a negative hold time such that there is a valid window. For example, \$t_{su} = 50\$  ps and \$t_{h} = -10\$  ps. Let's further suppose we're talking about flip-flops. What I am confused about is whether a given token must be stable from \$t_{su}\$ all the way to the clock edge, or just to \$t_h\$. If I am understanding your answer then it's the latter, whereas I had always thought it was the former.

Comment: It's the latter. The input can change in the 10ps time before the actual clock edge and not affect the output. Imagine there's a buffer with some *minimum* propagation delay in front of the flip-flop input.

Comment: Got it, thank you! If I may ask one follow-up, I'd like to try to understand what goes wrong if (1) \$t_h <0\$ and \$t_{su} < |t_h|\$ or (2) \$t_{su} <0\$ and \$t_{h} < |t_{su}|\$. That is, I'm hoping to understand "what would break". Is it just a matter of definitions as seems to be suggested above? Or would we argue as follows? For (1), we might design logic with a contamination delay such that a token arrives in the window \$|t_h| - t_{su}\$ before \$t_{su}\$, thereby garbling the token before it which didn't need to be stable until \$t_{su}\$. And similarly for the other case I guess...

Answer (score 0):

For `Hold Time` >If the difference between the data path and the clock path is negative, then a timing violation has occurred.

For `Setup Time` >If the difference between the clock path and the data path is negative, then a timing violation has occurred.